# How do I convert DateTime into string?

Tags: c#, sql

I have a method that requires 3 string so:

```
public <List> MethodName(string date1, string date2, string number)
{
  //
}
```

in my database `date1` and `date2` are stored as `DateTime` and number is stored as `Int` so how would I write a SQL query that will search based on these three parameters?

I have converted my `date1` and `date2` like this:

```
DateTime firstdate = Convert.ToDateTime(date1);
string fdate = firstdate.ToLongDateString();
  DateTime seconddate = Convert.ToDateTime(date1);
string sdate = seconddate .ToLongDateString();
```

My SQL query is:

```
  SELECT * From TableName 
  WHERE [Time] > @date1 AND 
  [Time] < @date2 AND [StaffCode] =@StaffCode;

command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@date1", fdate);
command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@date2", sdate );

command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@StaffCode", number);
conn.Open();
        SqlDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader();
        while (reader.Read())
        { get the data ...}
```

I am sure that my SQL query is wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Conversion:

```
             DateTime firstdate = Convert.ToDateTime(date1);
             string fdate = firstdate.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd");

             DateTime firstdate2 = Convert.ToDateTime(date2);
             string fdate2 = firstdate2.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd");
```

SQL Query:

```
           @"SELECT * From TestTable WHERE Time BETWEEN CONVERT(Date,@date1) AND CONVERT(Date,@date2) AND StaffCode=CONVERT(int,@StaffCode)"
           command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@date1", fdate);
           command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@date2", fdate2);
           command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@StaffCode", number);
```

Comment: i get error saying Must declare the scalar variable "@date2".

Comment: please give me the value of date1 and date2

Answer (score 5):

Since your database columns are already strongly typed, just ensure that your C# parameters are typed as `System.DateTime` and `int` (`System.Int32`) respectively before binding them to your query. Your sql is then simply:

```
SELECT col1, col2, col3
FROM TableName 
WHERE [Time] > @date1 AND 
      [Time] < @date2 AND [StaffCode] =@StaffCode;
```

If you allow for inclusive dates, you can use BETWEEN, i.e.

```
WHERE [Time] BETWEEN @date1 AND @date2 
    AND [StaffCode] = @StaffCode
```

i.e. avoid the need to [convert a Date to a string](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) altogether. Wherever possible, try and keep a strong type system all the way through your code, both C# and SQL - this will save a lot of pain during conversion. e.g. if possible, see if you can change the signature to:

```
public List<MethodName>(DateTime date1, DateTime date2, int number)
{
  // Bind the DateTimes, not a string!
  command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@date1", date1);
  command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@date2", date2);
  command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@StaffCode", number);
```

**Edit** Don't use `SELECT *` - use `SELECT Col1, Col2, ...`

Comment: its not working? command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@date1", date1) - for all three i am getting the entered value but in my reader its shows null? and where would i include System.int32? i have updated my question showing the way i did.

Comment: The c# type `int` is the same as the .net type `System.Int32`. Can you provide more info w.r.t. 'reader shows null' (are you calling `ExecuteReader` and then trying to bind data on the result?)

Comment: Suggest that you don't use `SELECT *`, and instead `SELECT Col1, Col2 ...` etc. This makes it easier to identify which column you are binding when you parse the reader. Please post your reader parsing code?